# Make a loop that draws lines in processing

Tags: java, processing

I have this piece of code, and i am wondering how to make a loop that will draw these lines... Every 50 pixels on the x-axis... I am curious as to how this can be done and would like to use a loop rather than manually drawing each line! 
The following is the code for the lines... Please any help would be much appreciated!

```
  //set sidewalk
fill(255,255,255);
rect(0,490,500,10);
line(50,490,50,500);
line(100,490,100,500);
line(150,490,150,500);
line(200,490,200,500);
line(250,490,250,500);
line(300,490,300,500);
line(350,490,350,500);
line(400,490,400,500);
line(450,490,450,500);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fill(255,255,255);
rect(0,490,500,10);

for (int i = 50; i <= 450; i+=50) { 
  line(i,490,i,500);    
}
```

maybe this way.

Comment: I'd recommend `for (int i = 50; i < ...` instead of `int i; for (i = 50; i < ... ` since the i only needs to exist in the for loops scope, it won't be used outside of it, but right idea, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Shiffman does a really good job of explaining how to do this in his book **Learning Processing**. You might want to look at example 6-1, 6-2 and 6-3 available on the [companion site to the book](http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/) as they lead up to how this problem is being solved. Shiffman shows this with a while loop and shows a similar code snippet with example 6-6 with it in a for loop similar to the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your interest lies in Visualization, another good source for learning Processing is **Visualizing Data** by *Ben Fry*.

And all the examples in this book comes with the Processing itself. Selecting File -> Examples..., then you can choose which example to see and to play with.